# Unknown 'VisualforceArrayList.Receiver_of_commodity__r' property

Tags: visualforce, outputfield

I'm getting this error: Unknown 'VisualforceArrayList.Receiver_of_commodity__r' property
on vfp.
I want to show the contents of this variable inside the vfp, and i am using a custom controller.  I appreciate any help

Controller:

```
public List <Opportunity> getEndereco(){
   system.debug('idOpp= '+idOpp);
    if(enderecoConta == null) {
        enderecoConta = [SELECT Id, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.CEP__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c, 
                        Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Municipio__r.Name, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Bairro__c, 
                        Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Estado__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Numero__c, owner.lastname,
                        owner.Email,owner.CPF__c 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id =: idOpp
            LIMIT 1];
    }
    return enderecoConta;

}
```

vfp:

```
<tr><th id="title1">Local da Entrega:</th>
       <td><apex:outputField value="{!Endereco.Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c}"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more of your controller/extension and visualforce page. I'm not sure if Salesforce will automatically query data on related fields if it's included in a Visualforce page (if you're not using a custom controller), but the `Encereco` variable makes me think that it's part of your custom controller/extension. At any rate, using `{!Endereco.Recibidor__r.Rua__c}` requires some specific code and variable naming, and I'm not seeing that in the current version of your question (so there's little we can do right now to help pinpoint the issue).

Comment: Hi, is it easier to understand now?

Answer (score 0):

So, your issue is that

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Endereco.Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c}"/>
```

is accessing the method

```
public List <Opportunity> getEndereco(){...}
```

But the outputField renders a scalar and the method returns a list.

In Visualforce, to display collections, you need to define markup that iterates over the collection like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Endereco}" var="e">
  <tr><td><apex:outputField value="{!e.<apex:outputField value="{!Endereco.Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c}"/></td></tr>
```

The above creates one table row per collection element

Now, perhaps your application intends to only display the first Opportunity.  In this case, change the Controller method to return a single object:

```
public Opportunity getEndereco(){

  if(enderecoConta == null) {
    enderecoConta = [SELECT Id, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.CEP__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c, 
                    Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Municipio__r.Name, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Bairro__c, 
                    Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Estado__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Numero__c, owner.lastname,
                    owner.Email,owner.CPF__c 
        FROM Opportunity 
        WHERE Id =: idOpp
        LIMIT 1][0];
  }
  return enderecoConta;
}
```

}